# Meine Kinder haben (considering sie as pronoun)/ habt(considering ihr as pronoun) hungrig

Tags: standard-german

Which one should be correct -

Meine Kinder haben (considering sie as the pronoun)/ habt(considering ihr as the pronoun) hungrig.

Comment: _hungrish_ isn't a german word. You probably meant _Hunger_ instead.

Comment: or you probably meant *hungrig*.

Comment: lol, my bad i was reading the words in english while writing them in german. yes, it is hungrig. @tofro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is correct.

Either you use the noun:

> Meine Kinder **haben Hunger**.

or you use the adjective (with *sein*):

> Meine Kinder **sind hungrig**.

The latter is an 1:1 equivalent to the English

> *My kids are hungry*.

Answer (score 4):

When you talk about your kids to someone else, you can say

> Meine Kinder/Sie **haben Hunger**.

or

> Meine Kinder/Sie **sind hungrig**.

So, as in English, you use 3rd person plural.